# howto find out which git submodule current directory belongs to

Tags: bash, git, git-submodules, fish

## setup

i have a `git` repo located in `/home/v/git_repo`, in which i have a submodule localted in subdirectory `./a/b/c`.

```
$ cat /home/v/git_repo/.gitmodules
[submodule "foo/bar"]
    path = a/b/c
    url = git@github.com:username/repo.git
```

having the full path or only the in-repository subpath (that i have implemented in helper script `git-where-in-repo-am-i-currently`)

```
$ pwd
/home/v/git_repo/a/b/c/something

$ git where-in-repo-am-i-currently
a/b/c/something
```

## question

i want to find out (preferably in `fish`) which submodule this path belongs to: e.g

```
$ git which-submodule (pwd)
foo/bar
```

to later use it to query that submodules status like

```
$ git -C (git rev-parse --git-dir)/modules/(git which-submodule) status
on branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'
```

and ultimately display this information in my prompt (that part is already implemented)

## what i tried

parsing the output of

```
$ git -C (git rev-parse --show-toplevel) config --file=.gitmodules --get-regexp "path"`
submodule.foo/bar.path a/b/c
```

and comparing my sub-directory path to that of a submodule, but it was rather a mess, with splitting pathes into arrays and all kinds of hacks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the usual setup you've described here, with the worktree nesting matching the submodule nesting, you can

```
mytoplevel=`git rev-parse --show-toplevel`
abovethat=`git -C "$mytoplevel"/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel`
```

Then,

```
echo ${mytoplevel#$abovethat/}
```

will get you the submodule path in the superproject, or you can

```
echo ${PWD#$abovethat/}
```

to get your current directory's path relative to the superproject.

So:

```
me=`git             rev-parse --show-toplevel`
up=`git -C "$me"/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel`
subpath=${me#$up/}
git -C "$up" config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' ^$subpath$
```

gets you the current repo's submodule name and path from the config entry in its superproject.

---

Git can be useful in any imaginable build system, though; it doesn't impose restrictions on how things outside its remit are set up. So short of an exhaustive search of the filesystem namespace you can't be sure you've found everybody using any worktree as a submodule checkout, there's just no reason for Git to care how a repository is used.

For instance, if multiple projects all need to run off the same submodule rev, you can have a single repo and worktree serve as a shared submodule for them all: rather than have to go through every single one of them and do synchronized checkouts, and then trusting that you haven't missed one, just use one repo, with one worktree, and point everybody using it at that.

For workflows with that need, this can be compellingly better than the usual setup, all users by definition see a synchronized, current submodule revision and any client who needs to know "what's new" with an update can e.g. `` git -C utils diff `git rev-parse :utils` HEAD ``, every submodule user effectively has their own tracking branch and can use all of Git's tools to help stay current or resolve conflicts.

---

So, to recreate your setup, I do:

```
git init git_repo; cd $_
mkdir a/b; git init a/b/c; cd $_
mkdir something; touch something/somefile;
git add .; git commit -m-
cd `git -C .. rev-parse --show-toplevel`
git submodule add --name foo/bar ./a/b/c -- a/b/c
git add .; git commit -m-
```

Then I get this when I try it:

```
$ find -print -name .git -prune
.
./a
./a/b
./a/b/c
./a/b/c/something
./a/b/c/something/somefile
./a/b/c/.git
./.gitmodules
./.git
$ git grl
core.repositoryformatversion 0
core.filemode true
core.bare false
core.logallrefupdates true
submodule.foo/bar.url /home/jthill/src/snips/git_repo/a/b/c
submodule.foo/bar.active true
$ cd a/b/c/something
```

```
$ me=`git             rev-parse --show-toplevel`
$ up=`git -C "$me"/.. rev-parse --show-toplevel`
$ subpath=${me#$up/}
$ git -C "$up" config -f .gitmodules --get-regexp '^submodule\..*\.path$' ^$subpath$
submodule.foo/bar.path a/b/c
```

```
$ echo $me $up $subpath
/home/jthill/src/snips/git_repo/a/b/c /home/jthill/src/snips/git_repo a/b/c
```

If there's a difference between this setup and what you've described, I'm missing it, I've got the directory structure, the submodule name, the start directory... if you'll step through that and find where the setup or results diverge from yours I think that'd help.

Comment: thank you, but i want to account for the _unusual setup_ as my daily operation often consists of fixing messed up repos.

Comment: The setup you describe in your question is usual, and the answer works for that. Generally it's a good idea to describe the situation you want help with when asking for help, I think you'll find most people here just assume you've done that.  For any _particular_ submodule setup, there's an answer.  But "submodule" itself is just a characterization of how a repo's being used, Git's your servant, not your master, it can do just about anything you ask of it.  You don't get to control what other people ask it to do with their repos, just as they don't get to control what you ask it do with yours.

Comment: as you see, i had the module nesting `foo/bar` different from the tree nesting `a/b/c` neverthelless, when trying your code both `mytoplevel` and `abovethat` pointed to `/home/v/git_repo` so it did not work on my end. any idea?

Comment: I've edited in my results here, only next step I can think of is to play spot the differences.